# Spring resttemplate SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory vs HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory performance difference

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am using spring RestTemplate created using `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. but i discovered that there is `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` which uses Apache HttpComponents.

Did any rationalized which one is good in terms of performance? and could share the both of the resttemplate configuration which concludes the result?

Comment: Off topic: I avoid `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` cause it does not support many features, like follow redirect, zipped content, cookies, etc ...